# Load multiple files using Azure Data factory or Synapse

Tags: azure-data-lake, azure-synapse

I am moving from SSIS to Azure.
we have 100's of files and MSSQL tables that we want to push into a Gen2 data lake
using 3 zones then SQL Data Lake
Zones being Raw, Staging & Presentation (Change names as you wish)

What is the best process to automate this as much as possible
for example build a table with files / folders / tables to bring into Raw zone
then have Synapse bring these objects either full or incremental load
then process the them into the next 2 zones I guess more custom code as we progress.

Comment: Could you please elaborate the question about your requirement?

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement can be accomplished using multiple `activities` in Azure Data Factory.

To migrate SSIS packages, you need to use SSIS Integrated Runtime (IR). ADF supports SSIS Integration which can be configured by creating a new SSIS Integration runtime. To create the same, click on the Configure SSIS Integration, provide the basic details and create a new runtime.

Refer below image to create new SSIS IR.

[image]

Refer this [third-party tutorial](https://www.sqlshack.com/move-local-ssis-packages-to-azure-data-factory/) by **SQLShack** to Move local SSIS packages to Azure Data Factory.

Now, to copy the data to different zones using `copy activity`. You can make as much copy  of your data as your requirement using copy activity. Refer [Copy data between Azure data stores using Azure Data Factory](https://www.sqlshack.com/copy-data-between-azure-data-stores-using-azure-data-factory/).

ADF also supports Incrementally load data using Change Data Capture (CDC).

**Note:** Both Azure SQL MI and SQL Server support the Change Data Capture technology.

Tumbling window trigger and CDC window parameters need to be configured to make the incremental load automated. Check [this official tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-incremental-copy-change-data-capture-feature-portal).

The last part:

> then process them into the next 2 zones

This you need to manage programmatically as there is no such feature available in ADF which can update the other copies of the data based on CDC. You need to either create a separate CDC for those zones or do it logically.